# Force scala.Predef initialization on application start without affecting the code

Tags: java, scala, static-initialization, predef

Initialization of `scala.Predef` class is lazy heavyweight operation which may cause unexpected slowdown of application and will become a trouble in situations when timing matters (like programming contests).

```
val a = new Array[Integer](10)
a(5) = 3 //slowdown on this line
```

So can I turn off it's laziness and force `scala.Predef` initialization on application start using only scala compiler or VM options without making changes in the code?

Comment: If you're needing this level of optimization, perhaps you should not be coding on the JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. You can initialize an object by calling it, like this

```
Predef    // ensures the body of Predef is initialized
val a = new Array[Integer](10)
a(5) = 3
```

Still, you will probably not have initialized the `ArrayOps` class which is involved in `a.apply`. Lazy class initialization is a property of the JVM. If you do benchmarks, that's why you usually give it a "warmup" run first, so that all involved classes have been loaded first.